# Add or update (Set) endpoint using Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I would like to automate setting and ocassionally updateing my Azure VMs using Azure PowerShell. I have success in both Add and Set, but unfortunately (and obviously) Add gives error if the endpoint already exists and Set gives error if the endpoint does not exist yet.

I wrote the following script:

```
$acl = New-AzureAclConfig

Set-AzureAclConfig –AddRule –ACL $acl –Order 100 –Action Allow `
    –RemoteSubnet "xxx.1.1.0/24" –Description "Permit"

Get-AzureVM –ServiceName myservice –Name myvm | 
    Add-AzureEndpoint –Name SqlEndpoint –Protocol tcp –LocalPort 1433 `
    –PublicPort 1433 –ACL $acl | 
    Update-AzureVM
```

Changing the Add-AzureEndpoint to Set-AzureEndpoint makes the script to work in the existing endpoint scenario.

I would not like to maintain 2 scripts, and always know which one to run just because this Add- vs Set- difference, instead I would like to combine the 2 execution logic into one. I suppose I need some conditional logic, and the ability to query whether the endpoint exists or not. Unfortunately I can not figure it how to query if the endpoint exists

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a conditional logic and determine whether the endpoint already exists using the [Get-AzureEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495158.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName myservice –Name myvm
if ($vm | Get-AzureEndpoint -Name SqlEndpoint)
{
    $vm |
        Set-AzureEndpoint –Name SqlEndpoint –Protocol tcp –LocalPort 1433 –PublicPort 1433 –ACL $acl | 
        Update-AzureVM
}
else
{
    $vm |
        Add-AzureEndpoint –Name SqlEndpoint –Protocol tcp –LocalPort 1433 –PublicPort 1433 –ACL $acl | 
        Update-AzureVM
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear for me where the script is referring the endpoint name when checking for the existence (I may have more than one endpoint)

Comment: You are right - I forgot to include the name (updated my answer).